# How to merge lvm

Tags: partition, lvm, disk-usage, lsblk

I don't know what my colleague exactly did but I know that he was trying to increase the size of LVM. For now I can see such an output after executing the command `lsblk`:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0             2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda             8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda2          8:2    0   39G  0 part
│ ├─rhel-root 253:0    0   95G  0 lvm  /
│ └─rhel-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─sda3          8:3    0   60G  0 part
  └─rhel-root 253:0    0   95G  0 lvm  /
```

As you see, there are two same names `rhel-root` under `sda2` and `sda3`, and both of them are mounted on thr root directory `/`.

However, the output of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  3.9G  9.6M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   35G   28G  7.3G  80% /
/dev/sda1             1014M  285M  730M  29% /boot
tmpfs                  783M  8.0K  783M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                  783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1001
```

It seems that the size of `/` is still 35G, meaning that it is not expanded.

It seems that I need to merge `sda3` and `sda2` but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Output of `lvs`:

```
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root rhel -wi-ao---- 94.99g
  swap rhel -wi-ao----  4.00g
```

Output of `vgs`:

```
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  rhel   2   2   0 wz--n- 98.99g    0
```

Output of `pvs`:

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel lvm2 a--  <39.00g    0
  /dev/sda3  rhel lvm2 a--  <60.00g    0
```

Output of `vgdisplay`:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               98.99 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25342
  Alloc PE / Size       25342 / 98.99 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               tPY1JO-AwK2-ULra-Matz-5VVy-lxWK-CL60ng
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague has successfully extended the `rhel-root` LV with `lvextend`, so one part of it is now on `sda2` and another on `sda3`. But the filesystem inside the LV has not been extended yet.

There is just one `rhel-root` LV, but `lsblk` shows it here in a way that can be a bit confusing: it shows the total size of the LV apparently in association with each individual part.

The `sda2` and `sda3` PVs are already merged into the `rhel` VG, so LVs within that VG can grow beyond the limits of a single PV. Apparently your colleague wanted to avoid the risks associated with editing the partition containing the root filesystem on-the-fly, and just created a new partition using the new space, and added it as a new PV to the existing VG. In my opinion, this is the safest way to extend a VG on a bootable disk: although it leaves you with multiple partitions-as-PVs which may offend your sense of neatness, it really has no other significant effect.

---

At this point, if you really want, you can still remove `sda3` and extend `sda2` instead. The procedure is as follows:

First, very carefully use `lvreduce` to shrink the `root` LV back to what it used to be. You can use the LVM backup files at `/etc/lvm/archive` to find out the exact size, or you could use `lvdisplay -m /dev/mapper/rhel-root` to see how many extents are located on the `sda2` PV, and use that value. **If you choose to do this, you must be very careful not to shrink the LV any smaller than the current size of the filesystem inside it:** you don't want to cut off the tail end of the filesystem, not even a tiny bit.

Then remove the now-empty `sda3` PV from the `rhel` VG with `vgreduce rhel /dev/sda3`, then edit the partition table to delete `sda3` and extend `sda2`, use `partprobe /dev/sda` to make the system accept the new partition table while the disk is in use (or reboot if `partprobe` is not available or fails to do the job), then `pvresize /dev/sda2` to extend the `rhel` VG by extending the `sda2` PV to take up the new space. Use `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/rhel-root` to re-extend the `root` LV.

Now you are at the same point your colleague got to, but without the aesthetically-displeasing `sda3`.

---

The last step your colleague missed is actually extending the filesystem to take advantage of the increased capacity of the LV. By the presence of `/run` in `df -h` output, and the VG name `rhel`, I assume this system is RHEL 7 or newer. So the default filesystem type is XFS, which means the command to extend the filesystem will be:

```
fsadm resize /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

or

```
xfs_growfs /
```

Note: think carefully before doing this, as **there is currently no production-quality tool to shrink a XFS filesystem, neither on-line or offline.** So once you extend the filesystem, you won't be able to shrink it back to a smaller size.

This command will be the same, no matter whether you chose to remove `sda3` and extend `sda2` instead, or keep your colleague's work as-is.